# PostgreSQL runs out of connections in .NET Core EF Core

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, ef-core-3.1

I have a web api project where the db is postgres and after sometime post gres runs out of connections as it is not allowing connections as all.

It is a big project and I am using az functions as well and I have reviewed all the queries and I am using ToListAsync and FirstOrDefault on the queries.

What else can be the issue? Also, is there a package that I can run on my code to see where the issue can be. I am using .NET Core 5. dbContext is injected through the DI constructor

Any ideas are welcomed

Comment: Most likely your code doesn't close the database connections and/or isn't using a connection pool. Check the results from pg_stat_activity to see the current connections and how long these are idle. We handle a 128 million database transactions daily over an average of 13 active connections.

Comment: @FrankHeikens what am I looking at in pg_stat_activity? What does it provide me? Is there a document that I can read to find out to check the parameters that signifies that issue is in the code?

Comment: @FrankHeikens Also, how do I know if the code is using connection pool? We are using dbContext for each of our table like we do in .net core which is the repository class

Comment: Check the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW And I know nothing about .NET can't help you with that.